# Search Manager for Android

Tags: android, search, toolbar, manager

Нужна помощь.В тулбаре есть поиск, где будет вводиться информация и при нажатии на клаве на ентер дожен открыватьса гугл с введеными даными. 
Никак не могу понять в документации и в примерах, как сделать поиск, который должен искать информацию в гугле. На данный момент придумал только так: передавать введеные через интент

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(**данные**));
    startActivity(intent);
```

но не понимаю, как получить эти данные, чтобы сделать каст в стринг для этого метода

```
 public Intent(String action, Uri uri,
        Context packageContext, Class<?> cls) {
    setAction(action);
    mData = uri;
    mComponent = new ComponentName(packageContext, cls);
}
```

Мне кажется, есть какой-то другой способ, немного понятней.

Вот мой код:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_toolbar, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_map:
            transaction.replace(R.id.container, new MapsFragment()).commit();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_search:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Нашел хорошую статью, в которой описаны пример работы с [SearchManager](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener)

Тепер код выглядит так:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_toolbar, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            // this is your adapter that will be filtered
            return true;
        }

        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            //Here u can get the value "query" which is entered in the search box.
            if (!query.isEmpty()) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + query));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            return true;
        }
    };
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(queryTextListener);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```